# What does the 'I' mean in this block of code in R?

Tags: r

```
M_2nd <- lm(I(log(Y))~(.)^2, data=Proj2)
```

That is the code in question, what does the 'I' mean?

Thank you

Comment: See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/AsIs, and also paragraphs 3 and 4 of "details" in https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/formula

Comment: Did you check `?I` ?

Answer (score 0):

I has to do with the (powerful) formula syntax in which *some* terms are decomposed.

For example the formula knows that `(.)^2` becomes the cross product of all terms, plus interactions.

The `log()`, however, should "stay as is" and the way to express that is the `I()` (I think: "idendity()") function.

Comment: Thank you for that. im having some issues in R.